# Using PHP $_SESSION variable to store large amonts of data

Tags: php, session

I'm currently storing a fair amount of data in the $_SESSION variable. I'm doing this so I don't need to keep accessing the database.

Should I be worried about memory issues on a shared server?

Can servers cope with large amounts of data stored in the $_SESSION variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I be worried about memory issues on a shared server?

Yes - session data is loaded into the script's memory on every request. Hence, you are at risk of breaking the individual per-script memory limit. Even if you don't hit the limit, this is really inefficient.

Accessing data from the database on demand is *much* better.

Comment: Thank you - will look into requesting data on each page request

Answer (score 3):

.. in addition to what @Pekka wrote:

PHP sessions an not alternative to a caching solution !

You should investigate if your server has [APC](http://www.php.net/apc) available. You should use that on top of layer which accesses information from database (assuming you actually have an OO code).

Comment: Good point, seeing as this probably is what the OP wants to do

Comment: I do have an OO approach. The data on the other hand is not necessarily for caching purposes but merely a resource for storing data which can be add to and removed from. I can easily avoid storing this in a session and instead make a db request when manipulating.